# how to shift the right most box towards the left and of same size as of box1 and box2

Tags: html

I need help to bring the right most box with heading 'This is box3' and id = "bin" 
towards the left side just beside the '<- this is button 2' and '<- this is button 3'.

Also the size of the right most box should be of same size as of the other two boxes.

```
<html>

<body>
<div align="center"><font color="red"><b><span id="Error_App"></span></b></font></div><br>
        <font size=3><b>This is box1 </b></font>
        <table border=0 width=100%>
        <tr>
        <td width=35%>
        <select multiple="multiple" id="teams" style="width:100%;" size="10">
        <option value=AA>teamA</option>
        <option value=BB>teamB</option>
        <option value=CC>teamC</option>
    </select>
        </td>
        <td width=10% align="left">
        <input title='SelectTeamMem.' type="button" id="btn_1" value="this is button 1 ->"></input>
        </td>
    <td width=50%  rowspan= "3" valign = "center">
        <font size=2>This is box 3</font>
        <br>
        <select multiple="multiple" id="bin"  style="width:100%;" size="10">
        </select>
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
    <td>
    <div align="center"><font color="red"><b><span id="Error_App"></span></b></font></div><br>
        <font size=3><b>This is box 2 </b></font>
        </td>

        <td width=30% align="left">
        <input title='SelectTeamMem.' type="button" id="btn_2" value="<- this is button 2"></input>
    <br>
        <input title='SelectTeamMem.' type="button" id="btn_3" value="<- this is button 3"></input>

        </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td width=30% valign = "bottom">
        <select multiple="multiple" id="mems" style="width:100%;" size="10">
         <option value=16313>member1</option>
         <option value=16250>member2</option>
         <option value=15041>member3</option>
         <option value=15041>member4</option>
         <option value=15041>member5</option>
     </td>
        <td width=50% valign="center">
        <input title='SelectMembers' type="button" id="btn_4" value="this is button4 ->"></input>
        </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
```

Comment: It is difficult to figure out what you want to achieve specifically — attaching an image, or even creating a minimal test case (a code snippet, or on JSFiddle) would be very helpful.

Comment: Also, you may need css.

Comment: Hi Terry , I do not have the reputation yet to attach an image. I do want to achive anything with respect to functionality. It is just a layout requirement which I have explained. I have given the entire code here. All I want is  to reduce  the  gap between right most box and the buttons. And the width of the right most box should be same as the other two boxes on L.H.S. If you just run the html I have put in a browser, I hope you would understand.

Answer (score 0):

## Move away from the `<table>` layout and no one gets hurt!

### How can I lay this out without a table?!

#### There are two crucial details

For this example, we are going to rely heavily on:

1. `display: inline-block` — [look for the simple explanation here](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/) — basically, inline-block elements will place themselves on the same line whilst also allowing widths and heights
2. `vertical-align: middle` — [a little information here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align#Values_(for_inline_elements)) — basically, the inline elements will vertically center themselves on their line

#### The basic layout

Our layout consists of five crucial building blocks:

1. two `<div>`'s with `display: inline-block` — this creates two columns.
2. two `<select>`'s with `display: inline-block` — this allows buttons one and four to align themselves next to each of the selects in the left column
3. two `<button>`'s with `display: inline-block` — these are buttons one and four which line themselves next to each `<select>`
4. three `<label>`'s with `display: block` — this brings the labels above their respective select groups
5. The `<form>` that wraps these elements is given an appropriate width and `margin: 0 auto` to center everything horizontally. It prevents the right column from sliding underneath the left if the browser window isn't wide enough.

#### Put everything together and we get...

[image: example screenshot]

### Show me the example already!

Sure, here it is! You can run the code snippet at the bottom.

```css
div {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 20px 0 0 20px;
}
form {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 622px;
}

label {
    display: block;
    font-weight: bold;
}
select {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 200px;
}
button {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

#btn_2, #btn_3 {
    display: block;
    margin: 1.5em 0 0 225px;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="left">
     <label for="teams">This is box1</label>
     <select multiple="multiple" id="teams" size="10">
       <option value=AA>teamA</option>
       <option value=BB>teamB</option>
       <option value=CC>teamC</option>
     </select>

     <button name="SelectTeamMem" id="btn_1" value="this is button 1 ->">
      this is button 1 -&gt;
     </button>

     <button name="SelectTeamMem" id="btn_2" value="<- this is button 2">
      &lt;- this is button 2
     </button>

    <button name="SelectTeamMem" id="btn_3" value="<- this is button 3">
     &lt;- this is button 3
    </button>

   <label for="mems">This is box 2</label>
   <select multiple="multiple" id="mems" size="10">
    <option value=16313>member1</option>
    <option value=16250>member2</option>
    <option value=15041>member3</option>
    <option value=15041>member4</option>
    <option value=15041>member5</option>
   </select>

   <button name="SelectMembers" id="btn_4" value="this is button4 ->">
    this is button4 -&gt;
   </button>     
  </div>
       
  <div class="right">
    <label for="bin">This is box 3</label>
    <select multiple="multiple" id="bin" size="10">
    </select>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: thanks. The solution is perfect. Can it be done without using css. is there any element/attribute in html which can help me to get desired layout

Comment: @AbhijitGhosh - CSS is 100% required with this method... Why would you not want CSS?

Comment: I have other element on the page (which I haven't mentioned to state my exact requirement in an uncluttered way) , so using more and more css would just complicate things for me,although I understand how important css is to get the design proper. I am okay to compromise with little bit of perfection, can I achieve it by manipulating cellspacing or cellpadding or whatever (you will know better than me) to get the layout. If there is any such tweak which i can do by altering an attribute , please let me know. Thanks

Comment: @AbhijitGhosh - There is a way with tables, but it's messy and would give me a headache! I really do recommend that you move away from tables for layout where possible. That said, the form itself is completely contained and should easily slot into your existing layout as long as there is enough size to fit it.